# Mathematics of Anomalies in QFT

Tags: resource-recommendations, quantum-anomalies

As a mathematics student interested in theoretical physics, I found it very hard to study about anomalies in QFT in *standard* physics texts. They concentrate on particular examples (like chiral anomaly), however, I want to know about *general* properties of anomalies in a Quantum Field Theory. Do you know of any books, lecture notes, or any other references for a proper general properties of anomalies for a mathematics student?

Comment: Bertlmann's *Anomalies in quantum field theory* is a very solid textbook, for mathematically oriented physicists.